# Converting a python script to exe

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a python file to exe, by following this website:https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

I think I have done everything right, I have added the python to PATH and installed pyinstaller using "pip install pyinstaller" which I got the response "Succesfully installed". My script is named "draw.py" and it is on Desktop, so I change the directory and then run "pyinstaller --onefile draw.py" but I get the result "'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

I am sure that I have installed the pyinstaller, I am also sure that I have added python to PATH, because it starts up when I type "python" in command prompt.

I dont know where the problem is, I did everything the website told me to do correctly, I am pretty sure that I have missed something even though I did everything correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure to add pyinstaller to the environment variable? If yes, try "pyinstaller - F [fileName]. py".
Through your question, I learned that your shell did not read a program named pyinstaller. Have you carefully checked whether pyinstaller was added to the environment variable?

Comment: Yeah, thats something I forgot and thats also probably the reason of my problem. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

try auto-py-to-exe its more user friendly and you can install it with  `pip install auto-py-to-exe` and then restart terminal/cmd and type `auto-py-to-exe` and its GUI based so its super easy to use you just need python and a browser installed.
I hope this helps and btw it uses `pyinstaller` to generate exe so if your package is installed correctly then there should not be any problem

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it out if I fail with my current plan. Thanks for your reply!